# building a regex using a variable from another string in powershell

Tags: powershell

I want to pass a string into a powershell function that can be used to form a regular expression for replace... however, i'm not sure how to form a regular expression using another powershell string.  Consider the following example:

```
function renamer {
    param(
        [String]$prefix,
        [String]$path
    )

    $path = $path -replace "^$prefix", "./mynewpath"
    return $path
}


renamer -prefix "C:/mycoolpath" -path "C:/mycoolpath/proj1"

# What I want renamer to return is this:
#   /proj1
```

Comment: then remove what you're replacing it with: `$path -replace "^$prefix"`, is sufficient. Would recommend adding a `$prefix = [regex]::Escape($prefix)` as well.